# retrieve parameter from executeQueryAsync, javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, executequery

I'm trying to retrieve a parameter from a success method that is called within and executeQueryAsync using Javascript ECMA scripting.

I get tried follwing the suggestion here

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/08/07/passing-parameters-to-success-method-in-executequeryasync-sharepoint/

but I get the following error in the MicrosfotAjax.js file:

"The Collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested." in the alert(_returnParam); command, I get an undefined value when instead it should say "hello". I want to demonstrate a simple variable return before I get the success function to return listItemInfo array.

Thank you for your consideration

```
function Tblsrch(camlstr){
var siteUrl = '/sites/SIandT%20Project%20Intelligence';
var hello;
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('ISATestdata');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlstr);

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    var _returnParam;

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){_returnParam = onQuerySucceeded();}), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 

alert(_returnParam);

}

    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args){
       var listItemInfo = new Array();
       var rowInd = 0;
        var hello;
                    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
           // listItemInfo += '\nType:' + oListItem.get_item('Name2') + ' | ' + oListItem.get_item('Plan') + ' | ' + oListItem.get_item('Type1');

            listItemInfo[rowInd] = new Array(10);
            listItemInfo[rowInd][0] =oListItem.get_item('Name2');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][1] =oListItem.get_item('Type1');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][2] = oListItem.get_item('Plan');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][3] = oListItem.get_item('Analyse');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][4] = oListItem.get_item('Design');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][5] = oListItem.get_item('Build');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][6] = oListItem.get_item('Test');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][7] = oListItem.get_item('Run');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][8] = oListItem.get_item('SupportMaintenance');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][9] = oListItem.get_item('Link1');
            listItemInfo[rowInd][10] = oListItem.get_item('Link2');

            rowInd++;
        }
        alert(listItemInfo[0][0] + " " + listItemInfo[0][1] + " " +listItemInfo[0][2] + " " + listItemInfo[0][3] + " " +listItemInfo[0][4] + " " );
    var _returnParam = "hello";
return _returnParam;
    }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args){
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){_returnParam = onQuerySucceeded();}), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 

alert(_returnParam);
```

It's normal. `executeQueryAsync` is asynchrone, so `executeQueryAsync` is called (= an AJAX request is done), and immediately after, without waiting for the AJAX to be completed, you call `alert(_returnParam)` with _returnParam that is still void.

You need to call another function at the end of `onQuerySucceeded` if you want another action to be done.

By the way, I always thought that the Microsoft way is really difficult to use. I've created a library to deal with Sharepoint, if you are interested (it's called [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/)). For what you want to achieve, the code would be something like that (I've also review your code with the array):

```
$SP().list("ISATestdata", "/sites/SIandT%20Project%20Intelligence").get({fields:"Name2,Type1,Plan,Analyse,Design,Build,Test,Run,SupportMaintenance,Link1,Link2",where:"Name2 = 'Something'"}, function(data) {
  var listItemInfo = [];
  for (var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
    listItemInfo[i] = [];
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Name2"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Type1"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Plan"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Analyse"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Design"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Build"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Test"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Run"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("SupportMaintenance"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Link1"));
    listItemInfo[i].push(data[i].getAttribute("Link2"));
  }

  alert(listItemInfo[0][0] + " " + listItemInfo[0][1] + " " +listItemInfo[0][2] + " " + listItemInfo[0][3] + " " +listItemInfo[0][4] + " " );
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response AymKdn, really appreciate. If you call another function on onQuerySucceeded can you get that function to return a value back to Tblsrch (the function that gets used first)?

Comment: Ans as for your library, Ill see if I can give it a try, thanks :)

Comment: It's async, so no you cannot return a value. You need to call another function instead of returning a value.